# r swirl - can't run swirl course, get enigmatic error message

Tags: r, yaml, swirl

I've created a course using the `swirl` package in r. The yaml file is created fine.

```
new_lesson("lesson_name", "course_name")
demo_lesson()
```

However, I attempt to run the course but get the following error:

```
Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 61, column 32
```

This error is incomprehensible to me. Anyone who knows swirl has an idea of what it means, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. It was an indentation problem in the yaml document that the `swirl()` function was using to display the questions. How to find "line 61, column 32" is still mysterious to me, though.